# HTTPS Authentication with fetch() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a webpage in which there is a javascript function which has to call an external endpoint to get some response.

It was working fine till the time the endpoint was over http. But, now it on https.

I was using the fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in order to call the endpoint and do further processing.

This is how my function looked like:

```
async function fetchCoverageData() {
  if (!coverageData.host || !coverageData.project ||
      !coverageData.change || !coverageData.patchset) {
    throw 'Need retry, change info is unavailable yet for code coverage.';
  }

  console.log('coverage data reached here is', coverageData);  
  const url = REQUEST_BASE_URL + coverageData.project + "/" + coverageData.branch + "/" + coverageData.changeId;

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const responseJson = await response.json();

  if (responseJson.error) {
    console.error('Parse response body to JSON returned ' +
                  'error: ', responseJson.error);
    return null;
  }
  if (response.status == 404 &&
      responseJson.is_project_supported == false) {
    console.warn(' project is not supported for code coverage.');
    return null;
  }
  if (response.status == 500 &&
      responseJson.is_service_enabled == false) {
    console.warn('service is temporarily disabled.');
    return null;
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw `Need retry, request code coverage data returned http ` +
          `${response.status}.`;
  }
  return responseJson;
}
```

Now, I just want to ask, if I switch the external service to HTTPS, how exactly would I pass it to the fetch function? I need to set it as part of the Headers, but what exactly would I need to set in the headers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) to make this work?

Comment: there shouldn't be any real code changes between using http vs https, no special headers needed.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the issue is not with HTTPS but with some sort of authentication. It should be noted that this authentication issue can also work over HTTP but people mostly don't do that since it would be easy to intercept the credentials

Comment: @dandavis won't I have to setup some sort of connection before calling the endpoint with authentication? I mean, 1 way SSL or exchanging certificates before calling the endpoint?

Comment: @slebetman there is no issue as of now. I am only asking how to migrate and what all I will need to do.

Comment: Oh. OK. All you need to do is change the url from `http://` to `https://`. That is absolutely everything you need to do on the client side - there is no other change. On the server side it is a bit more complicated

Comment: `fetch("https://marine.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=44.4&lon=-82.34&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=json").then(x=>x.json()).then(console.info);` ; nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `fetch()` with HTTPS all you need to do is change the url form:

```
http://example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

Literally just add the `s`

Comment: Note that although TLS and SSL before it includes client authentication features in web browsers HTTPS is simply an encryption mechanism. Browsers do not support client authentication with HTTPS protocol (though you are free to use other authentication mechanisms such as cookies, Authorization header etc.)